# How to annotate an image on a HTML-page

Tags: html, css, markdown

I want to create a user guide in HTML format which contains screenshot images.
OK so far.
Then I want to add annotations to those images (which are screenshots of forms with some controls).
The annotations are describing those controls.
This will be done more than once (each time the form is changed,...)

There are no dynamic effects necessary, the annotations should be displayed statically.

What would be a simple, easily maintainable way to to this?

Instead of using pure HTML I have had good success with strapdown.js so far, only the annotations are a missing feature.

Any hints are welcome, maybe "annotation" is not a good description of what I am doing...

**edit**: the annotations should be displayed *on top of the image* (as would be done with a image editor and drawing a textbox directly in the image).

Comment: What do you mean by annotate an image? Just to provide some text beneath it explaining it?

Comment: this was probably voted down because its very vague. Better to be very specific about what you're trying to accomplish, what's not working. If you try asking stuff like "what libraries good for X" they get closed pretty quick :/

Comment: And this site prefers questions that can be answered, not discussed.

Comment: So in HTML terms, you want `figure` and `figcaption`?

Comment: for annotation editors, see [annotorious](https://annotorious.github.io/) or [markerjs](https://markerjs.com/) or [boxy svg editor](https://boxy-svg.com/) ([enable file export](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/418981-boxy-svg-com-bypass)) or [svgedit](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit) or [image-annotation](https://github.com/topics/image-annotation?l=javascript)

Answer (score 1):

`figure` and `figcaption` is pretty much intended for this, and with some css to overlay it on top of the image:

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
 <figure>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

K.I.S.S. - keep it simple, stupid

```
<img>
<br>Annotation
```